# Is there a way to position new text within an existing pdf keeping such that it's editable after?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, pdf, server, terminal

I want to create a pdf with pictures and text formatted a certain way — they all have to be arbitrarily positioned. I want to create such pdf on the server with terminal commands.

As I searched for the solution, I didn't find one. So I compiled some ideas to solve the problem; however, I still looking for a more direct one. I used the postscript compiler ENSCRIPT as a filter and then created a pdf by using the PS2PDF tool. Then I used the PDFJAM tool to position text in arbitrary position within the existing pdf. The following is the code I use to produce such a document. Although even this solution would help people who have the same problem, I welcome your suggestions of more efficient ways to handle this.

```perl
#!/bin/bash
# the following creates PDF with text
# options:
# -B — no header
# -f — font family and size
# --columns — make text grouped in columns
# -o - — to pass output 
echo "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | \
     enscript -B -f "Times-Roman12" --columns=5 -o - | \
          ps2pdf - pdf_with_text.pdf 

# the following tool creates pdf_with_text-pdfjam.pdf from the pdf_with_text.pdf moving it in the exact position of the page
# options: 
# -q — quiet mode
# --scale — scaling pdf_with_text.pdf if you need that
# --paper — resulting paper type
# --landscape — resulting paper orientation
# --offset — the most important part, set the offset of the top left corner of the source document in the resulting document. 0,0 point is in the middle (weird!)
pdfjam  -q --scale 0.20  pdf_with_text.pdf --paper letter \
          --landscape --offset "2cm -3cm"

# then we combine a new document and the existing one:
pdftk ./existing.pdf  stamp pdf_with_text-pdfjam.pdf output new_combined.pdf

=========================
I got the combined pdf:
 new_combined.pdf
with the text, I echoed in the first string, with the applied offset from the middle of the page.
```